# Lambda Query To Know How Many Members I'm participated With In Total

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a Table Like this:

[image]

I want to write a query to extract Employee info and the amount of people that are with me in different groups.

So the result will be like this:

[image]

I tried to select employee ids and distinct them, then iterate through them, and for every employee Id write a query to distinct the groups and then read the count of employees that are not equal to my selected employee Id.

Output was a messy code and I don't even want to write it here.

how can I write a query to get the result.

Here are my Classes:

```cs
public class AppraisalInteractionGroup
{
    public AppraisalInteractionGroup()
    {
        AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployees = new HashSet<AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployee>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Guid InteractionGroupId { get; set; }
    public string InteractionGroupTitle { get; set; } = null!;
    public Guid AppraisalId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployee> AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployees { get; set; }
}    

public class AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public long AppraisalInteractionGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual AppraisalInteractionGroup AppraisalInteractionGroup { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I have appraisal Id and I want to write a query to know how many people, each employee has interaction with.

AppraisalId is specified and I want to query just a specific Appraisal.

Interaction Groups define how employees have interaction with each other. When an appraisal is started an employee appraises all the employees that are within the same interaction group.

Comment: Show your classes. LINQ query is build from classes and navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following what you need but this might be it?

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x.GroupId); // change to InteractionGroupTitle? better to use an ID of some sort

var countPerEmployee = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
  var count = group.Count() - 1; // exclude myself?

  if (countPerEmployee.CointainsKey(group.Key))
     countPerEmployee[group.Key] += count;
  else 
     countPerEmployee.Add(group.Key, count);
}
```

Comment: Result is based on Groups. result should be based on Employees

Comment: Output is list of employee ids with a number that indicates how many people this employee is in interaction with

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, query should looks like this:

```cs
// input data
var appraisalId = ...

var query = 
    from ag in context.AppraisalInteractionGroups
    where ag.AppraisalId = appraisalId
    from ae in ag.AppraisalInteractionGroupEmployees
    group ae by new { ae.EmployeeId } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.EmployeeId,
        Count = g.Count()
    };
```